# How to calculate number of triangles and points after dividing a triangle n times?

Tags: geometry, triangles, learning

When having a triangle and dividing it n times, how to get the number of triangles and points?

```
      a
     / \
    /   \
   f-----d
  / \   / \
 /   \ /   \
c-----e-----b
```

**edit**: This triangle is part of an icosahedron as base geometry for a sphere, left it out due to jitter information. Then the assumptions took place.

Comment: Hope that I tagged right, don't no any mathmatic terms while english isn't my first language. Please tell me if/what is wrong, I'll update ASAP. Lack of naming conventions makes searching a horror too.

Comment: $N_{triangles}=4^n$
$N_{points}=3\cdot\frac{3^n-1}{2}$

Comment: If by "divide $n$ times" you mean subdivide each of the small triangles that resulted from the last operation, repeated $n$ times, then the number of triangles is a simple formula but the number of points would depend on how you create and count the vertices. On the second subdivision, do you exactly bisect each edge so that the new triangle inside $\Delta cef$ and the new triangle inside $\Delta def$ share a single vertex on the edge $ef$, and if so, do you count that vertex just once?

Comment: My previous comment assumed you subdivide the upside-down triangles too. If you don't, then there's no ambiguity about how you count the number of points.

Comment: My apologies for the delay - an emergency arised here and had to leave.

Comment: Δdef will be divided too and those vertices will be counted once for both (Δcef and Δdef). But it won't be a bore two know how it is calculated of those are counted twice.

Answer (score 1):

Each division multiplies the number of small triangles by $4$, and you start with one triangle at $0$ divisions, so the number of triangles after $n$ divisions is $4^n$.

The number of distinct horizontal sides of small triangles after $n$ divisions is

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}k=\frac{2^n(2^n+1)}2=2^{n-1}(2^n+1)\;.$$

There are the same number of distinct sides of small triangles parallel to each of the non-horizontal sides of the original triangle, so there are altogether $3\cdot2^{n-1}(2^n+1)$ distinct sides of small triangles after $n$ divisions.

Now let $p_n$ be the number of vertices after $n$ divisions; clearly $p_0=3$. If $n\ge 1$, there are $3\cdot 2^{n-2}(2^{n-1}+1)$ small sides after $n-1$ divisions, and the $n$-th division adds one vertex for each of those sides, so

$$p_n=p_{n-1}+3\cdot2^{n-2}(2^{n-1}+1)\;.$$

Thus,

$$\begin{align*}
p_n&=p_0+\sum_{k=1}^n3\cdot 2^{k-2}(2^{k-1}+1)\\\\
&=3+3\sum_{k=1}^n\left(2^{2k-3}+2^{k-2}\right)\\\\
&=3+\frac32\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}4^k+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^k\right)\\\\
&=3+\frac32\left(\frac{4^n-1}3+2^n-1\right)\\\\
&=2^{2n-1}+3\cdot2^{n-1}+1\;.
\end{align*}$$